# Asp.NET Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I've implemented caching on a file (XML) which gets sent to the graphs controls to render it.
However, I was told to implement caching in a way that can be easily switched on and off (meaning setting a value in web.config).

Is there a way I can turn caching on and off depending on a value in a web.config file? Thank you lots!

@oded the code you supplied doesn't fit in my scenario because I'd have to rewrite existing code for instance:

```
if(bool.parse(confi.... == "true"){
 if(Cache[x] == null){
  load the XML document and insert it into the Cache object }
 else{
 get the xml document from the Cache object. } }
```

else repeat myself by reloading the document from object.

I'm sure there's got to be a better solution to this.

Comment: You _have_ to rewrite you code if you need to switch things on/off depending on config. There is no way to keep the code as is and make it depend on config.

Comment: Note: "Cache" is not the same as "Session". Both store objects, but Session is user-specific and Cache is application wide (=all users get the same value).

Comment: and what about the following: 

Response.AddCacheItemDependency("CachedXml");
            if (isCacheEnable == true)
            {
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            }
            else if (isCacheEnable == false)
            {
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check for a value of a key in the `config` file.

In `appSettings` section:

```
<add key="cacheXML" value="true" />
```

And in your code check this:

```
if(bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cacheXML"]))
{
  // use caching
}
```

Note: this will throw an exception if the key does not exist in the app settings.

Note2: You should abstract away the dependency on configuration, so you can test your code without needed a config file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a documented way of creating caching profiles [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178606.aspx) - when your web.config contains the cache profiles you need, then make your pages use the profile by supplying the cacheprofile name to the [@outputcache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx) directive in the relevant pages.

Comment: He is talking about caching an XML file on the server - what has this to do with output caching?

Comment: he's tagged it as asp.net, so presumably he's talking about caching the result...  (at least I hope he is, that's the more efficient way to do things, no point re-processing the same xml over and over again!)

Comment: how can I disable the duration attribute? I the caching to be dependant on the XML file from which it gets its data?

Comment: see CacheDependency  (though I'm not sure if that can be configured from web.config) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could add an caching aspect to your business layer.

But that depends on how you implemented your business logic? Do you have a separate business layer and some kind of dependency injection (like Ninject) in place?

Comment: So, @Oded solution is the best way to go.

Comment: If you would have a separated business layer you could easily add a caching layer to it ...