# How to make caching dependent on a boolean value in web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asp.NET Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249017/asp-net-caching)

I'd like to be able to switch caching on or off depending on a value set in web.config file. Say for instance if the value is 'true' then caching is enabled. Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with the answers you got [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249017/asp-net-caching)?

Comment: the code you supplied doesn't fit in my scenario because I'd have to rewrite existing code for instance:

if(bool.parse(confi.... == "true"){
if(Session[x] == null){
load the XML document and insert it into the Cache object
}
else{
get the xml document from the Cache object.
}
}
else
repeat myself by reloading the document from object.

I'm sure there's got to be a better solution to this.

Comment: Then edit your original question and add detail, instead of asking a duplicate question with even less detail.

Comment: You could add an caching aspect to your business layer. But that depends on how you implemented your business logic? Do you have a separate business layer and some kind of dependency injection (like Ninject) in place?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a key in your web.config. like,

```
<add key="AllowCaching" value="true"/>
```

then where ever you want to do caching you may do:

```
DataSet dataSet;
    if(bool.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowCaching"]))
    {
        //do caching
        if (Context.Cache["YourDataKey"] == null)
        {
            dataSet = GetDataForDataset();
            object objDataset = (object)dataSet;

            Context.Cache.Insert("YourDataKey", objDataset, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30),
                System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
        else
        {
            dataSet = (DataSet)Context.Cache["YourDataKey"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //dont do caching
        dataSet = GetDataForDataset();
    }
```

where 30 is the number of seconds for which you want to hold data in cache.